# Fetch data returned by worker

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

How can i fetch the data returned by worker here??

```
import multiprocessing

def worker():

      """worker function"""
      return 'DATA'

if __name__ == '__main__':

      jobs = []
      for i in range(5):
          p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
          print p
          jobs.append(p)
          p.start()
```

OUTPUT :

```
DATA
DATA
DATA
DATA
DATA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a pool of workers and pass in some data to process:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(item):
    return item ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)

    for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, range(30)):
        print result
```

Comment: How to do the achieve the same if I have different workers,

import multiprocessing

def worker_1(item):

    return item ** 2

def worker_2(item):

    return item ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)

    for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, range(30)):
        print result

Comment: @maruthireddy: Why do you need two workers to do the same job? The pool is holding five workers.

Comment: These workers are different doing diffrent jobs.

def worker_1(item):
    return item**2

def worker_2(items)
    return sum(item**2)